# Join ON AND with laravel eloquent query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write the following sql query in laravel:

```
    select 
    `workers`.`first_name`, 
    `workers`.`last_name`, 
    `occupations`.`approval_date`, 
    `occupations`.`certification_date`, 
    `occupations`.`expiration_date`, 
    `occupations`.`type`, 
    `workers`.`photo` 

    from `worker_print_queue` 
    inner join `workers` on `worker_print_queue`.`worker_id` = `workers`.`id` 
    inner join `occupations` on `worker_print_queue`.`certification` = `occupations`.`type` AND `workers`.`id` = `occupations`.`worker_id`
```

I have written it in eloquent in the following manner:

```
$records = \DB::table('worker_print_queue')
                ->join('workers', 'worker_print_queue.worker_id', '=', 'workers.id')
                ->join('occupations', function($join){
                    $join->on('workers.id', '=', 'occupations.worker_id')
                            ->where('worker_print_queue.certification', '=', 'occupations.type');
                })
                ->select('workers.first_name', 'workers.last_name', 'occupations.approval_date',
                        'occupations.certification_date', 'occupations.expiration_date', 'occupations.type', 'workers.photo')
                ->get();
```

But I am receiving no results. I'm sure there is something I'm missing, just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this line

```
->where('worker_print_queue.certification', '=', 'occupations.type');
```

is comparing the column `'worker_print_queue.certification'` to the value `'occupations.type'`.

If you change it to use the `on` clause you should be fine:

```
->on('worker_print_queue.certification', '=', 'occupations.type');
```